# Prove function is always zero.

Tags: functions

Suppose $f$ is a function defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$. If for any square ABCD,

$f(A)+f(B)+f(C)+f(D)=0$.

How to prove that $f\equiv0$? Thanks!

Comment: Consider the case where A=B=C=D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- We take two squares A, B, C, D and C, D, G, H which share the C-D side. Then, it follows that $f(A)+f(B)=f(G)+f(H)$.
- Now, A, G, H, B is a rectangle. Take another rectangle A, I, J, G which shares the A-G side. It follows that $f(I)+f(A)=f(J)+f(G)$.
- We get $f(B)-f(I)=f(H)-f(J)$, subtracting the previous two equations. But then since B, I, G, H is square, we also have $f(B)+f(I)+f(H)+f(J)=0$. Together we get $f(I)+f(H)=0$.
- This means, the sum of two diagonals of a square is always zero.
- Next, inscribe a square E, F, G, H inside another A, B, C, D using the middle points of the edges of the latter. G-H is a diagonal, as is F-H. Therefore, $f(G)=f(F)$.
- Similarly, we can get $f(G)=f(F)=f(E)=f(H)=0$, since the sum of all is 0.
- Thus $f$ is identically zero since the choice of vertices was arbitrary.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you for the links!

Comment: Thank your so much! Very elegant!